# Checkbox triggers stackpanel expand/collapse animation

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, storyboard

I have WP7 application with simple phone page.

I have check box

```
<CheckBox Content="Click me" Margin="0,2,0,0">
```

When I check the checkbox I want Stack panel below it to expand.

```
<StackPanel Height="0" x:Name="MyStackPanel">
    <CheckBox Content="Condition"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Right now I tried this solution, but i receive exception that EventTrigger.RoutedEvent cannot be assign to Checkbox.Checked.

```
<CheckBox Content="Click Me" Margin="0,2,0,0">
    <CheckBox.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyStackPanel"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                     To="100"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </CheckBox.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

Do you have any ideas what is the best approach to implement such animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a control for what you require to do. You should be using the Expander control that iss part of the silverlight toolkit . There iS A  good two part tutorial about working with this control here on [WindowsPhoneGeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-ExpanderView-in-depth-Part1-key-concepts-and-API).

Basically, you use the expander control and implement your own custom controls for the header and the items.

Comment: is it the only possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

try `ToggleButton.Checked` instead of `CheckBox.Checked`